# How to return different statements in where clause ? (oracle)

Tags: oracle

I mean:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNCTION1(ID IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
BEGIN
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3 FROM TABLE1
WHERE COLUMN1<= Y AND (CASE WHEN ID < X THEN COLUMN1<COLUMN2 ELSE COLUMN2>COLUMN3 END),
AND COLUMN 3 = XYZ;

RETURN SOMETHING.

END;
```

I know **case statement does not** return an expression but a value. How can i use some kind of "conditional statements" or something to return expressions ? I use to do it easily in mysql with "IF conditional" but i don't know how to do it in Oracle 11g.
**EDIT:** Does it work the same, not only for where statemen but for select ?

Comment: I think you just need to change the `(CASE WHEN ID < X THEN COLUMN1<COLUMN2 ELSE COLUMN2>COLUMN3 END)` to: `(ID < X AND COLUMN1<COLUMN2 OR (ID>=X OR ID IS NUL OR X IS NULL) AND COLUMN2>COLUMN3)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use grouped `WHERE` conditions:

```
WHERE COLUMN1<= Y 
   AND ((ID < X AND COLUMN1<COLUMN2)
        OR(ID >= X AND COLUMN2>COLUMN3))
AND COLUMN 3 = XYZ;
```

Remember you really just want to get some boolean evaluations back here - as long as you can reduce your requirements to distinct sets of conditions you can put it into `WHERE` which will be plenty fast.

The time to use `CASE` is if you have overlapping criteria that you need to short circuit.

Comment: Does it also work in Select statement ?

Comment: @AlejandroBastidas no but what do you need to do in a `SELECT` here?  There is almost certainly another way to do it.

Comment: Not in this example, but if I needed to choose between two or more columns to build a Select statement depending of a variable value or column value, should it work? I'm kind of lost. Thank your very much.

Comment: Well you CAN use a case for that:  `SELECT MyField = CASE WHEN x>1 THEN ColumnA WHEN X<1 THEN ColumnB ELSE ColumnC`

Comment: I'm ready to continue translating procedures. Thank you very much. Even if it may be a simple issue, you really helped me out.